# GPM annual precipitation using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation, gpm

I'm trying to calculate GPM v6 annual precipitation using the Google Earth Engine,
but show this error:

> Line 11:
>  ee.ImageCollection(...).select(...).filterDate(...).filterBounds(...).clip 
> is not a function

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
Map.addLayer(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var ano_inicial = 2000
var ano_final = 2020
var mes = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
var intervalo = ee.List.sequence(ano_inicial,ano_final)
var inicio =  ee.Date.fromYMD(ano_inicial,1,1);
var fim = ee.Date.fromYMD(ano_final,12,31);

var GPM = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06')
    .select('IRprecipitation')
    .filterDate(inicio,fim)
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .clip(geometry);
    
var GPM_Anual = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  intervalo.map(function (ano) {
    var annual = GPM.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ano,ano,'year'))
    .sum()
    .multiply(24*30*12)
    .clip(table)
    return annual
    .set('year',ano)
    .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(ano,1,1))
    }))

Export.image.toDrive({
  image : GPM_Anual,
  description : 'GPM_annual_2000_2020',
  scale : 1000,
  region : geometry,
  maxPixels : 1e9
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Don't clip, you can only clip Images not Image Collections. Either map over the collection and clip everything or just leave it out if it's not completely necessary

Answer (score 0):

clip is a function you can apply to images only, you are now trying to apply to the entire imageCollection. Instead you need to map over the entire collection (=select individual images) and clip it.

```
.map(function(img){
      return img.clip(geometry)
    })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ad4f0384def03fafe12fc94a3ab5f5d

Comment: I can't run the rest of your script because the variable table is unknown to me. But defintely the approach seems to be allright if you are after the images that contain the summed value for each year.

Comment: when export to google drive show  error
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/f4a2be718b6bd1dc952e94d59de9cc56

Comment: You can't export an imageCollection with the export.image.toDrive() function. So you have to export each image seperately or use toBands() on the imageCollection to get that done

Comment: I used .toBands() command but I can't export it yet, can you check it? https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd79cb3fc80ce14275d9bd8af622add7